# On the convergence of a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac { p(p+1) \cdots (p+n-1) }{ q(q+1) \cdots (q+n-1)} \right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am struggling with the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac { p(p+1) \cdots (p+n-1)  }{ q(q+1) \cdots (q+n-1)}  \right)^n,$$ where $p,q>0$. I have checked the Dirichlet and ratio test so far, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which is bigger, $p$ or $q$?

Comment: Indeed.  Trivially, if $p\geq q$ then the terms do not approach zero and the sum can not possibly converge.  For the other case, recommend trying to phrase things in terms of the gamma function and using [stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function) to continue.

Answer (score 3):

Without Sterling, but only with elementary tools:

- If $p \geq q$, then
  $$
  \frac{p+k}{q+k} \geq 1
  $$
  for all $n\geq 1$ and $0\leq k\leq n$, so the product is at least $1$, and the series diverges trivially as the general term is lower bounded by $1^n=1$.
- If $p < q$, then
  $$
  \frac{p+k}{q+k} < 1
  $$
  for all $n\geq 1$ and $0\leq k\leq n-1$, so the product is at most $\frac{p}{q}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{p+k}{q+k} < \frac{p}{q} < 1$, and the series converges by comparison with the geometric series of general term $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The series has all positive terms. Hence to judge convergence you can use the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) that says that if $a_n \sim b_n$, then

$$\sum a_n \text{ converges} \iff \sum b_n \text{ converges}$$

To find to what your general term is asymptotic to you can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to deal with the factorial.